# Is there a word for hangover thirst?

Tags: single-word-requests, slang

Is there a single word to describe the feeling of thirst/dryness when hungover?

I'm translating a song from Russian and just 'hangover' will probably work, but i'm wondering if there's maybe a slang word for this specifically.

Comment: There are some choice phrases here: [The Language of Hangovers](http://brookstonbeerbulletin.com/the-language-of-hangovers/). There aren't many idioms concerning thirst, but "wooden mouth" and "mouth like a fur boot" are quite good, Alas, there are no single-word terms.

Comment: There is also *fur-tongued*.

Comment: Oo, thank you! Love the expressions, and that article was sure a fun read.

Comment: I've asked some friends for suggestions. If they come back to me, I'll pass them on.

Comment: Are you looking for an informal term.?

Comment: For the song - yes, but after stumbling onto this i'm interested in what terms English has for it in general. My upvote doesn't show up since i'm new, but thank you for putting your answer together! If you've heard any informal terms as well i'd love to hear them.

Comment: Interesting question! Since you’re new to Stack Exchange, you might also be interested in the site for [ell.se].

Comment: It's always interesting to see which languages do or do not have words for certain phenomena. Can you share the Russian word with us? In Dutch would say "nadorst", literally translated "afterthirst".

Comment: In German we have "Brand", which is something like "Im burning for something to drink". I think that describes the actual thirst better than for example the "cotton mouth", which is more of a description of your mouth than your thirst. But I don't know an English word either :(

Answer (score 18):

I’ve often heard the term ***cotton mouth*** to describe this phenomena.

The [Oxford learner’s dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/cottonmouth#cottonmouth) labels this as `US informal`. An [online wellness article](https://www.positivehealthwellness.com/pain-relief/get-rid-cotton-mouth-quickly-easily/) indicates that the chief symptom of cotton mouth is "a severely dry mouth” and says that one way to avoid it is by limiting your alcohol intake.

I’m not sure how widely recognizable this term might be outside of the U.S., but it might work well as slang in a song lyric. It even has the same number of syllables as *hangover*, so it might be an easy fit for you.

Comment: +1 wanted to add that this is alluding to how dry your mouth would be with cotton balls in it

Comment: In my experience, **_cotton mouth_** has the connotation of being caused by cannabis smoking.

Comment: @chbaker0 - I think it’s most commonly associated with that, yes.

Comment: In my experience a cottonmouth is something you find crawling through the weeds.

Comment: Similar to this, I've heard fuzz mouth and fuzzy mouth.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not aware of a single word, a common UK phrase however is to

> [have a mouth like the bottom of a parrot's cage](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22mouth%20like%20the%20bottom%20of%20a%20parrot%27s%20cage%22&start=10)

I can't find a definition of it as such but there are plenty of examples online where the meaning is clear from context. It conveys both thirst and the way everything tastes vile when you wake up with a hangover. Like the bottom of a parrot's cage because it's dry and covered in...crap.

Comment: Probably can't cram it in a song but this is delightfully colorful, thank you.

Comment: @jensa There is also 'rough as a badger's arse' to refer to the general feeling of being hungover. https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22AS+A+BADGER'S+ARSE%22 Again, difficult to fit into a song... :)

Comment: Why do I have a feeling Pratchett would've managed to get both of those into a song.

Answer (score 5):

The Scottish word ***[drouth](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/drouth)*** (rhymes with truth) would be appropriate here. It means thirst and depending on context can mean that specifically from a hangover. It also meets the criteria of being [slang](http://literalbarrage.org/blog/2005/01/25/your-scottish-slang-word-o-the-day-drouth/).

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage and thank you for your answer. We appreciate your desire to help, but we’re looking for complete answers that provide explanation or back up. Please consider [edit]ing your answer to explain why it is right, ideally with [references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/2573). Unsupported answers will be deleted. (If your answer was deleted before you read this comment and no other answer made the same suggestion already, feel free to post an improved version of your answer.)

Comment: I considered going for drouth, but most of the examples i could find were indicating that beer was *about* to be drunk, rather than had already been!

Answer (score 2):

Not what you asked for, but it might give you some ideas:

> His mouth had been used as a latrine by some small creature of the night, and then as its mausoleum. During the night, too, he'd somehow been on a cross-country run and then been expertly beaten up by secret police. He felt bad.

Kingsley Amis, *Lucky Jim*

Answer (score 0):

In New Zealand and Australia people sometimes talk of having the [**dry horrors**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dry_horrors).

Comment: I've seen & heard this term used to mean a dry mouth, but your link specifically (and exclusively) refers to 'the psychotic symptoms of withdrawal suffered by an alcoholic', which is an almost completely different thing.

Comment: Yes, that is a very odd definition. I have never heard the term used to mean anything other than a dry mouth. Even the sample quotes seem to refer to dry mouth rather than psychoses.

Comment: So why not link to a definition that supports the meaning you suggest?

Comment: That's a good idea! The reason I don't do it is that I can't find one. Most _usages_ I have found refer to the dry mouth, but the only actual _definitions_ I have found from reputable sources (the above definition and one from a paper dictionary) basically define it as _delerium tremens_. So perhaps it's a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score -1):

If there is no word for you that fits, try to adopt the german word 'Brand'. Which is a metaphor to something like the following: my mouth needs water to fight the fire which burned my mouth to ashes due to alcohol use(of course it's technically a dehydration of your body). It's common to say that if your thirst is huge, regardless its reason is hangover or just too salty lunch.